# Pre-selected cells for UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

In my application I have this tableview. Each cell contains a label and a UISwitch (default state off).

[image: Image1]

It works great and I use it to filter value contained in another tableview.
My question is, how can I do to have a pre-selection on load?
I'll explain better, if I select [section 1 (Stato) - rows 1, 3] then I press the done button I'll make the view disappear. If I present again the viewController I'd like to see the same switches pre-selected.

initially I thought I have to save the indexPath, but it didn't work.

This is my tableView code:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return names.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView {
    let view: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 18))
    let label: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 5, tableView.frame.size.width, 18))
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(18)
    let string: String = names[section]
    label.text = string
    label.textColor = .redColor()
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    view.addSubview(label)
    view.backgroundColor = ColorHex().UIColorFromHex(0xEEEEEE)
    return view
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    var number: Int!

    switch section {
    case 0:
        number = 1 //reset filter
        break
    case 1:
        number = statusesDict.count
        break
    case 2:
        number = queuesDict.count
        break
    case 3:
        number = typesDict.count
        break
    case 4:
        number = severitiesDict.count
    default:
        break
    }

    return number
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell: TicketsFilterCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellTicketFilter", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TicketsFilterCell

    cell.delegate = self

    if self.selectedIndexPathArray.contains(indexPath) {
        cell.switchFilter.setOn(true, animated: false)
    } else {
        cell.switchFilter.setOn(false, animated: false)
    }


    if(indexPath.section == 0) {

        let text = “Reset all”

        cell.textFilter.text = text

    } else if(indexPath.section == 1) {

        let text = statusesDict[indexPath.row]?.capitalizedString

        cell.textFilter.text = text

    } else if(indexPath.section == 2) {

        let text = queuesDict[indexPath.row]?.capitalizedString

        cell.textFilter.text = text

    } else if(indexPath.section == 3) {

        let text = typesDict[indexPath.row]?.capitalizedString

        cell.textFilter.text = text

    } else if (indexPath.section == 4) {

        let text = severitiesDict[indexPath.row]?.capitalizedString

        cell.textFilter.text = text

    }


    return cell

}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
{
    return false
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

    if let index = self.selectedIndexPathArray.indexOf(indexPath) {
        self.selectedIndexPathArray.removeAtIndex(index)
    } else {
        self.selectedIndexPathArray.append(indexPath)
    }

    let cell = self.tableview.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TicketsFilterCell
    cell.toggleSwitch()


}

{
    let indexPath = self.tableview .indexPathForCell(cell)

    if (status == true) {

        if self.selectedIndexPathArray.indexOf(indexPath!) == nil {
            self.selectedIndexPathArray.append(indexPath!)
        }


        //update dictSelected
        switch (self.tableview.indexPathForCell(cell)!.section) {
        case 0:
            print("section 0, reset all filter")
            self.dictSelectedReset.updateValue(true, forKey: String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            break
        case 1:
            //take data from status
            print("section 1, value -> \(statusesDict[(indexPath?.row)!]) for row \(String(indexPath!.row))")
            self.dictSelectedStatus.updateValue(statusesDict[(indexPath?.row)!]!, forKey: String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            break
        case 2:
            //take data from queue
            print("section 2, value -> \(queuesDict[(indexPath?.row)!]) for row \(String(indexPath!.row))")
            self.dictSelectedQueue.updateValue(queuesDict[(indexPath?.row)!]!, forKey: String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            break
        case 3:
            //take data from type
            print("section 3, value -> \(typesDict[(indexPath?.row)!]) for row \(String(indexPath!.row))")
            self.dictSelectedType.updateValue(typesDict[(indexPath?.row)!]!, forKey: String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            break
        case 4:
            //take data from severity
            print("section 4, value in -> \(severitiesDict[(indexPath?.row)!]) for row \(String(indexPath!.row))")
            self.dictSelectedSeverity.updateValue(severitiesDict[(indexPath?.row)!]!, forKey: String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            break
        default:
            break
        }

    }
    else {

        if let index = self.selectedIndexPathArray.indexOf(indexPath!) {
            self.selectedIndexPathArray.removeAtIndex(index)
        }


        //update dictSelected
        //if exist, delete re-tapped

        switch (self.tableview.indexPathForCell(cell)!.section) {
        case 0:
            if (dictSelectedReset.keys.contains(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))) {
                dictSelectedReset.removeValueForKey(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            }
            break
        case 1:
            if (dictSelectedStatus.keys.contains(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))) {
                dictSelectedStatus.removeValueForKey(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            }
            break
        case 2:
            if (dictSelectedQueue.keys.contains(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))) {
                dictSelectedQueue.removeValueForKey(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            }
            break
        case 3:
            if (dictSelectedType.keys.contains(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))) {
                dictSelectedType.removeValueForKey(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            }
            break
        case 4:
            if (dictSelectedSeverity.keys.contains(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))) {
                dictSelectedSeverity.removeValueForKey(String((indexPath?.row)! + 1))
            }
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }


}
```

where

```
selectedIndexPathArray = [NSIndexPath]()
```

and this is CellProtocol:

```
protocol CellProtocol : class {
func switchButtonTapped(WithStatus status : Bool, ForCell cell : TicketsFilterCell)
}
class TicketsFilterCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var textFilter: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var switchFilter: UISwitch!

weak var delegate : CellProtocol!

class var reuseIdentifier: String? {
    get {
        return "TicketsFilterCell"
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}


//  Uncomment here to show switches that are preselected on load

//    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
//        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
//        self.delegate .switchButtonTapped(WithStatus: selected,  ForCell: self)
//    }


@IBAction func switchTapped(sender: UISwitch) {

    self.delegate.switchButtonTapped(WithStatus: sender.on, ForCell: self)

}

// select UISwitch and change status
func toggleSwitch() {
    if self.switchFilter.on {
        self.switchFilter .setOn(false, animated: true)
    } else {
        self.switchFilter .setOn(true, animated: true)
    }
    self.delegate.switchButtonTapped(WithStatus: self.switchFilter.on, ForCell: self)
}

}
```

As you can see I tried to solve the problem using the func setSelected in the CellProtocol but if I uncomment and use it I have nil error.

How can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: store the selection state on your model and restore it back when you present the cell; working with index paths to detect the selected cells in that context is a kinda wrong approach because it seems you are not aware of any permanent storing of the selection state currently.

Comment: I tried to store selected values with NSUserDefault but it isn't the right way. Can you explain better please? An example would be helpful

Comment: I did not say to use the user-default, but you clearly do not even store those value even for current runtime session; it seems to me you just store this value locally for the current view's lifecycle and when the view dismissed you lose the that information immediately – that is why I told you, you need to try to implement the model properly and store the information there as long as you need.

Comment: Thanks you but I already know that I need to save values to a stored model, but I don't know how to do, so I opened this question

Comment: I think you need to create a model, because it seems you don't have any yet; you just hardcoded populating the cells in the delegate class, which is pretty much means you store the data on the _view_ layer not on the _model_, and that is why you face to difficulties, because when the _view_ dismissed you lose the data as well; try to isolate the two layers nicely as it is supposed to be and that is your solution.

Comment: @holex Data that populates tableview is saved 4 different arrays dynamically and that's ok for me, do I need to create another one?

Comment: 4 arrays... why? you don't need 1 more, you need to get rid of 3 current ones; and put that only and one array onto your _model_ layer, where you will intend to store probably the rest of the information (e.g. label, etc.) for your cells, but because I don't know anything about your storing policy (how long a certain data needs) the only thing I can say is implement your _model_ for your expectations; because it seems you don't have any _model_ yet as I told you before (storing the data on _view_ is a bad option).